# Router.use requires middleware function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mean-stack

So I'm trying to seperate my login routes in a seperate JS file called login_routes.js

I keep getting this specific error:

> TypeError: Router.use() requires middleware function but got a Object
>       at Function. (/Users/ethanthomas/Desktop/mean-stuff/express-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:446:13)

Not entirely understanding what it's asking me to `implement`?

**login_routes.js:**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.route('/login')

.get(function(req, res, next) {
    res.send('this is the login form');
})

.post(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('processing');
    res.send('proccessing the login form!');
});
```

**server.js:**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var adminRoutes = require('./app/routes/admin_routes');
var loginRoutes = require('./app/routes/login_routes');

app.use('/admin', adminRoutes);
app.use('/login', loginRoutes);


//send our index.html file to the user for the home page
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});

//start the server
app.listen(1337);
console.log('leet is the magic port');
```

Comment: `var adminRoutes = require('./app/routes/admin_routes');` is an object, and you cannot pass it to `app.use`. You need to pass a function, similar to what you are doing for route `/` in `server.js` file.

Comment: you never exported the router out of **login_routes.js**.

Comment: Please how can I do either of these things? Pretty new to JS/MEAN stack dev.

Answer (score 4):

Your **login_routes.js** should look something like this (in the context of express):

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// GET request to /login
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    // do something
});

// POST request to /login
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    // do something
});

module.exports = router;
```

In your **app.js** you use

```js
var login_routes = require('./login_routes');
...
app.use('/login', login_routes);
...
```

Have a look at the code generated by the [express-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-generator) module. That is a starting point for express webserver apps.

Answer (score 3):

People have already offered hints at the solution in comments.

The first issue is that you need to export your "sub" app from `login_routes.js`. To do so, change this:

```
var app = express();
```

Into this:

```
var app = module.exports = express();
```

Secondly, you are—probably unintentionally—creating routes for `GET /login/login` and `POST /login/login`. To solve this, use this in `login_routes.js`:

```
app.route('/').get(...).post(...);
```

This is because the root path in your sub app (the one in `login_routes.js`) will get mapped to the path used in `app.use()` in your main app (`server.js`).

Comment: The second statement helped me, thank you! I wasn't aware of the mapping :D

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

**login_routes.js:**

```
exports.get = function( req, res ) {
  res.send('this is the login form');
};

exports.post = function( req, res ) {
  console.log('processing');
  res.send('proccessing the login form!');
};
```

**server.js:**

```
var loginRoutes = require('./app/routes/login_routes');

app.get('/login', loginRoutes.get);
app.put('/login', loginRoutes.post);
```

Comment: That doesn't do the same. For one, you're splitting the `GET` and `POST` into two separate routes, and instead of exporting two symbols it would suffice to export the `app`.

Comment: I'd like to use get/post methods only on /login...any ideas?

Comment: @user3649245 I edited my answer for same `/login` route for both get and post.

Comment: @robertklep Please remove downvote. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

**login_routes.js:**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.route('/login')

.get(function(req, res, next) {
    res.send('this is the login form');
})

.post(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('processing');
    res.send('proccessing the login form!');
});

module.exports = router;
```

just writ `module.exports = router` then it will be work